# Option.zip returns List, not Option

Tags: scala

Standard library documentation describes `zip` partial signature as `def zip[B](that: GenIterable[B]): Option[(A, B)]` but `Some(1) zip Some(2)` returns a `List((1,2))` not `Some((1,2))`. Is it a case of buggy implementation or buggy documentation?

Comment: Buggy documentation if it's the scaladoc.

Comment: Note that Scalaz provides a `Zip` type class that works as expected here (although you'd need `some(1) fzip some(2)`).

Comment: See [SI-8394](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8394).

Comment: Note that starting `Scala 2.13`, [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#zip[A1%3E:A,B]\(that:Option[B]\):Option[\(A1,B\)]) has been modified to produce an `Option`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Buggy documentation.

`zip` is actually defined on `Iterable`, and it's applicable to `Option` due to the implicit conversion `option2Iterable` (this is explicitly stated in the documentation if you look closely).

For this reason `Option` is first converted to an `Iterable` and then the `zip` operation is supported.

This is done for code reuse, but it misses some case in which `Iterable` methods make sense directly on `Option` without need of an implicit conversion.

Here's a relevant discussion in mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/MFU5PPt_jYw

If you actually need to `zip` two options, you can use this workaround:

```
(opt1 zip opt2).headOption
```

Also, as Travis noted in the comments, you could alternatively leverage scalaz `Zip` type class, although you would have to use `fzip` instead.

```
opt1 fzip opt2
```

Comment: Using `zip` on options return an `Option`. Why is that  ( https://pastebin.com/gkEbJmua )?

Answer (score 4):

Use type level functional library [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) to combine contexts. Context in this case is option type. Avoid using `(opt1 zip opt2).headOption` as this results in `Iterable[(Int,Any)]` instead of `None` for example if opt2 is a None.

```
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.syntax.apply._

val resultTupled: Option[(Int, Int)] = (opt1, opt2).tupled

val resultAdded: Option[Int] = (opt1, opt2).mapN((a, b) => a + b)
```

Above will take care result in None if either of opt1 or opt2 is None.

Little more detail:

- `tupled` above is from cats `Semigroupal`. It is defined as Product and Tupled is extension method for convenience otherwise you had to do `Semigroupal.tuple2(opt1, opt2)`.
- `mapN` is ditto a convenience method for  `Semigroupal.map2(opt1, opt2)(_ + _)`