# Unfolding multiple Optional variables in Java 8

Tags: java, scala, option-type

I have the following problem. Let's say  you have 2 `Optional` variables

```
Optional<Contact> c1 = ...
Optional<Contact> c2 = ...
```

and a method which needs 2 variables of type Contact

```
void match(Contact c1, Contact c2) {...}
```

and you need to unwrap both c1 and c2 `Optional` vars and pass them into the `match()` method.

My question is **"Which is the most elegant way to do that in Java 8?"**

So far I've found 2 ways:

1. by using isPresent

   ```
   if (c1.isPresent() && c2.isPresent()) {
       match(c1.get(), c2.get());
   }
   ```
2. by using nested ifPresent

   ```
   c1.ifPresent((Contact _c1) -> {
       c2.ifPresent((Contact _c2) -> {
           match(_c1, _c2);
       });
   });
   ```

Both ways are terrible in my opinion. In Scala I can do this:

```
for {
    contact1 <- c1
    contact2 <- c2
} yield {
    match(contact1, contact2);
}
```

is there a way in Java 8 to do it neater than I outlined above?

Comment: What do you want to do if the Optional isn't present? Just ignore or throw an exception?

Comment: IMHO option 1) is clearer than the Scala code as it has less magic.

Comment: Option 2 can be written `c1.ifPresent(_c1 -> c2.ifPresent(_c2 -> match(_c1, _c2)));` also, no need to create blocks.

Comment: @Tunaki, if the value is not set, then match(..) should not be called at all. Also, if you omit braces, the whole construction still remains embedded. I'm not saying it's too bad, but code readability is still suffering

Answer (score 13):

Solution you provided in scala is just syntax sugar for using flatMaps internally. You can use flatmaps in Java 8 too (but there are no syntax sugar for it).

```
c1.flatMap(contact1 -> c2.flatMap(contact2 -> match(contact1, contact2)));
```

it is almost the same thing as solution 2 you provided. You also can use applicative functor from https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react (I'm one of contributors) or any other functional java 8 library.

Applicative functor

```
Optional<String> o3 = Maybe.fromOptional(o1).ap2(String::concat).ap(o2).toOptional();
```

For-comprehension

```
Do.add(o1)
    .add(o2)
    .yield(a->b->a.concat(b));
```

Comment: It has to be `ifPresent` since match has return type void, and if match will return f.e. boolean it could be `Optional<Boolean> result = c1.flatMap(contact1 -> c2.map(contact2 -> match(contact1 ,contact2)))`

Comment: it is a syntax sugar indeed, but it makes code readable. Regarding, cyclops-react lib, looks great, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Actually, a better way to do it in scala (and without syntax sugar) is something like `c1.zip(c2).map { case (a,b) => match(a,b) }`.
Does java have `zip`?

Comment: It doesn't use syntax sugar but still use internal optional2Iterable conversion (as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26346031/5619043). So to do same thing in scala you'd need to perform that conversion yourself that will lead to some boilerplate code.  You can use cyclops-react to get zip operation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35608063/5619043

Answer (score 7):

You could desugar the Scala for-comprehension to map/flatMap in Java 8 with a function like:

```
public static <T,K,V> Optional<V> map2(Optional<T> opt1, Optional<K> opt2, BiFunction<T, K, V> f) {
    Optional<V> result = opt1.flatMap(t1 -> opt2.map(t2 -> f.apply(t1, t2)));
    return result;
}
```

And then pass your function *match*

Comment: The two optionals don't need to have the same type: you can write

    public static <T, K, V> Optional<V> map2(Optional<T> opt1, Optional<K> opt2, BiFunction<T, K, V> f) {
        Optional<V> result = opt1.flatMap(t1 -> opt2.map(t2 -> f.apply(t1, t2)));
        return result;
    }
}

Comment: You are right, i am going to change the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the arguments not having values as an exception then you could handle them like:

```
try {
    match(c1.orElseThrow(NoVal::new), c2.orElseThrow(NoVal::new));
} catch (NoVal ex) {
    ...
}
```

If they aren't an exceptional case then I would go with your first option as being more explicit about your intent. In my view it's pretty clear and readable, and easy to change to use `orElse` if you wish to switch to using defaults if the optionals are empty.